# React Eslint destructuring-assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am using eslint rule `react/destructuring-assignment` which throws. How can I destructure this?

```
getStuff(model = this.state.model) {
   // some stuff
}
```

Comment: What you doing there isn't destructuring

Comment: This has nothing to do with destructuring. What exactly is the error message here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESLINT doesn't allow to use `this.state.model` and it suggests you to utilize destructuring:

```
const { model: stateModel } = this.state
getStuff(model = stateModel) {
```

But, I'm afraid as it's inside react class component. Thus, you can't define a const or var before method definition. You should disable the eslint for the line:

```
getStuff(model = this.state.model) { // eslint-disable-line
```

---

Alternatively, you may use like:

```
 getStuff(model) {
   const { model: stateModel } = this.state
   const passedModel = model ? model : stateModel

   // then work through passedModel
}
```

---

Hmm, I can think of this should do the trick:

```
getStuff({state: {model}} = this) {
```

But, frankly I have never used such. Just try and let me know.

**Update**:

You may also use like:

```
getStuff(model) {
  const { model: stateModel } = this.state || { model: model }
  console.log(stateModel)
```

Or, simply:

```
getStuff(model) {
  const { model } = this.state || { model }
  // ----------------- similar to { model: model }
  console.log(model)
```

Comment: What about `getStuff({ model } = this.state) { ...`?

Comment: No. Will not... There's still `this.state` inside params and thus it will not be allowed.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I have updated but am not fully sure if the  syntax will work like  such inside function params.

Comment: When you say "it will not be allowed" do you mean by ESLint or by syntax? Because syntactically, that's allowed.

Comment: By ESLint I mean.

Comment: `getStuff({ model } = this.state)`. This would destructure passed argument and look for model. And lint says model of state is never used.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Wont this use the state even when parameter is passed in?

Comment: @ATOzTOA sorry, din't get you.

Comment: If I do `getStuff()` it will use model from state. If I do `getStuff(customModel)`, it will still do model from state.

Comment: I din'g get it properly. But I think you want reverse condition in my last example code `const { model } = { model } || this.state`?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your need, you want to have a default var for a model from state and be able to pass it also if needed.

```
getStuff(passedModel) {
   const { model } = this.state
   const toUseModelInMethod = passedModel || model
   // or 
   const toUseModelInMethod = passedModel ? passedModel : model
}
```

If you just want to get the model from this.state it's simple

```
getStuff() {
   const { model } - this.state
}
```

Also you can pass your state to the method

```
getStuff({ model }) {...}
this.getStuff(this.state) // linter is not happy
// that's is better
getStuff(model){...}
const { model } = this.state
this.getStuff(model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't destructuring. A function would look like this:

```
function getStuff({ property1, property2 }) {
...
}
```

The above example would pull property1 and property2 from whatever object is passed to the given function.